# Having some trouble with an infinite animation in css

Tags: html, css

I added an infinite news ticker to a website I am building. I am just having problems making it revolve constantly without cutting out and then restarting after 20 seconds. Note: I am using pure CSS for this because I want it to be a static website.

This is the test code I am using:

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animated section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

section .scroll {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

section .scroll div {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: animate 40s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -20s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}

section .scroll div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<section id="animated">
  <div class="scroll text1">
    <div>
      Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place
      <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place
      <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: wdym by static website?javascript on frontend is also considered static.

Comment: Do you need to mark up the text that's scrolling with those spans? If not you can put all your text into an attribute like title, then use before & after selectors with `content: attr(title);` to essentially duplicate the ticker text into two elements. Now you can place the elements next to each other and scroll the two clones individually to make the illusion of continuous looping

Comment: **What if you only have a short word**? How do you want to prevent not having a huge space on the right? The same problem applies to really long ones. The string that attaches to the ending one is actually (obviously) a cloned sentence. (or multiple clones - to fit the element width)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are starting your translation at 100% so it has to take 50% of the animation to get it onto the screen and depending on the size of the ticker, it can take longer before it shows as it has to travel further.

If you push the ticker off the screen with padding instead (and compensate by padding the right of ticker so all the ticker items show), it will start on the right of the screen instantly and therefore you will not get the pause:

```css
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.ticker-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 40s;
  animation-name: ticker;
}

.ticker__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker-wrap">
  <div class="ticker">
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Place <span> holder -</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**If you want to keep your code layout**

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animated section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

section .scroll {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-left:100%;
}

section .scroll div {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: animate 40s linear infinite;
  padding-right:100%;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}

section .scroll div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<section id="animated">
  <div class="scroll text1">
    <div>
      Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place
      <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place
      <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span> Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>Place <span> holder -</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This significantly reduces the pause. Which is good. But is there a way to make it as flawless as ones used in news channels using just CSS?

Comment: The only way to may it loop without any white space is to use js so that it clones your item as it moves off screen to the left and moves it to the end of the ticker, otherwise you will always get that space as it  finishes the last and comes back round to the first.  I would say that if you want to use a ticker, it is better to use js rather than css as you would get a constant speed of animation rather than a speed dependent on how long the ticker is

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how to get rid of the 20 second delay before the ticker restarts, using only CSS. One way is to position the div which contains the text back just before the end of the animation. For example:

```
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
     transform: translateX(100vw);
     visibility: visible;
  }
  99% {
     transform : translateX(-100vw);
     visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
      transform: translateX(100vw);
      visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

However, to get rid of the whitespace just before the next animation sequence begins while accommodating variable length news items, keeping the ticker readable on small screens, coping with really large screens when there is little news, all while keeping the ticker going at a constant rate will require some calculation as other commentators have mentioned.

This would be possible to do in advance (i.e. not using Javascript) if the site is static, animating each news item separately and calculating the animation duration and animation delay for each, but changing anything would require recalculations so for maintainability using Javascript might be better.